# Is strong law of large numbers an improvement of weak law of large numbers?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, information-theory

Is strong law of large numbers an improvement of weak law of large numbers ?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called strong.

Comment: The conclusion is stronger, but it requires more stringent assumptions. In short: when both applies, the conclusion of the strong law is stronger than that of the weak law (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strong law of large numbers refers to almost sure convergence, while the weak law of large numbers corresponds to the convergence in probability.

The laws of large numbers are called strong and weak respectively because almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability, but the converse need not be true. Hence, we can say that the strong law is a strengthening of the weak law.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suggest you edit the answer the add the comment made by Clement C for better understanding.